# loop for with class functions error when condition too high

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, segmentation-fault

Last time I'm constantly getting an error with for-loop.

The easiest way to show it is:

```
#include <iostream>
class Class
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    Class(int a);
    void get();
};

Class::Class(int a)
{
    number=a;
}

void Class::get()
{
    std::cout<<number<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int amount=4;
    Class* p[amount];
    for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        delete p[i];
        p[i]=new Class(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        p[i]->get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program is returning 255, and while debugging I'm getting a SIGSEGV signal - segmentation fault.

I found one thing very strange: when `amount=3` or less program works properly. I'm going to use it for over 700 elements, so I've found this quite disappointing.

I'm using Windows 7 and Code::Blocks 13.12 with GNU GCC Compiler.

What should I change in this program so that it works properly? I'm pretty sure that's only my small knowledge about c++ or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be aware that `Class* p[amount];` when `amount` is not a compile time constant is a gcc compiler extension, and is not part of the C++ language specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what's going on (see comments):

```
// This allocates `amount` spots for pointers
Class* p[amount];
// Your pointers are not initialized yet
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
{
    // You are trying to delete what they point to
    delete p[i]; // <<== This is undefined behavior
    p[i]=new Class(i);
}
```

You should not call `delete` until after you have allocated the objects being deleted. Otherwise, it's undefined behavior, i.e. your program may crash.

Finally, you need to delete the pointers after you are done with them to avoid memory leak. You could use a vector of smart pointers for that (recommended), or simply add another loop to your program, like this:

```
int amount=4;
Class* p[amount];
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
{
    p[i]=new Class(i);
}
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
{
    p[i]->get();
}
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
{
    delete p[i];
}
```

Comment: delete(0) is fine, and Class* p[amount] = {} would fix it

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks for the comment! Although that is most certainly true, it's pointless to delete something before first use. OP sounds like a beginner C++ programmer, so I'd rather not teach her something she shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class* p[amount];
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
{
    delete p[i];
    p[i]=new Class(i);
}
```

You should remove the line `delete p[i];` since the array `p` is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 2):

You are consistently calling `delete` on pointers that don't point to dynamically allocated objects:

```
Class* p[amount]; // array of uninitialized pointers

delete p[i]; // oops
```

Comment: As I've said. just my ignorance... Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

initialize p[i] along with declaration.
Class* p[3] = {0}; delete has built in null check, with that you will not get any error

you should be getting error even when amount is 3 or less than three

Comment: Deleting a pointer to an invalid memory location causes undefined behaviour, so it might cause an error or it might not, there's no "should" about it.

Comment: @Oktalist agree, but it can't be consistent for less than 3 no issues and more than 3 always a segmentation fault.